# How to make an event when my CollectionViewCell is double clicked?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to make an event when my `collectionview` cell is double clicked

Is the `UIGestureRecognizer` the only one way to solve this problem?

It's very long and difficult code for me to solve...

Is there any support from `UICollectionView` or `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: A `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not the *only* way to solve this “problem”, but it's probably the *easiest* way. Show us what you've tried and explain what you didn't like about it.

Answer (score 0):

In your -cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapped:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And this method:

```
    -(void)doubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap{
        UICollectionViewCell *doubleTappedCell = tap.view;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:doubleTappedCell];
}
```